# How do I tell if a Green Fig is ripe?

Tags: harvesting, figs

There is a Kadota (I think) fig tree in our yard - the fruit is massive, slightly squishy, and the holes at the bottom of the figs are starting to open and they're starting to pale.

How do I tell if they are ripe or not?  They're only drooping around a centimeter and are growing bigger daily.

Comment: I have another type of fig, which turns brown and becomes soft to the touch when ripe.

Answer (score 7):

I've got a green fig tree too (as of 9 months or so) and was unsure how to pick a ripe one too, but I've had plenty of practice now. Just wait until they give slightly under pressure from a gentle squeeze, similar in texture to brown figs but usually without any signs of browning.

In my case the green figs were ripe at the same size range as with brown figs.

If you do see one that's got some hint of brown it's probably overripe and may be starting to rot on the tree.

After picking the first one and testing the sweetness, you may prefer to let them hang until they're a bit more "squishy to the touch", but that's up to your taste.